# How to specify Height of a dropdown Spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner and it has 13 item. When clicked i want to show a dropdown list of 100dp height (not individual item height) and it need to be scrollable vertically. So it will show 3-4 item. I want a scrollable view of some kind, but height goes to the bottom of the screen.

here is what i tried:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/cycle_spinner"
            android:background="@color/myoffwhite"
            android:popupBackground="@color/myoffwhite"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">
        </Spinner>
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_spinner"
            android:background="@color/myoffwhite"
            android:popupBackground="@color/myoffwhite"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">
        </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the individual item in the dropdown menu,
You can specify the height by overriding as below.

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    view.getLayoutParams().height = [specify height here];
    return view;
}
```

For the size of the dropdown menu itself, 
you may want to use below.

```
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    try {
        Field popup = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        popup.setAccessible(true);

        ListPopupWindow window = (ListPopupWindow)popup.get(spinner);
        window.setHeight(123); // in pixel, replace with your size
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work. spinner still expands to the end of the parent.